# Projections between two affine algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

What are the two projections $\mathbb{A}^2\to\mathbb{A}^1$, that exhibits $\mathbb{A}^2$ as a product $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$ in the category of affine algebraic sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\operatorname{Spec}A \times \operatorname{Spec}B$ is $\operatorname{Spec} (A \otimes B),$ and accordingly the projections are induced by canonical inclusions in the tensor product. In particular, projections $\mathbb{A}_k^2\to\mathbb{A}_k^1$ come from $k[x] \hookrightarrow k[x,y]$ and $k[y] \hookrightarrow k[x,y].$

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but as a newbie to Algebraic Geometry I don't understand how does the maps stated above gives maps from $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$?

Comment: @AnishRay Maps of affine schemes/varieties correspond to ring homomorphisms by the respective equivalence of categories.

Comment: Then how do these maps exhibits  $\mathbb{A}^2$ as a product $\mathbb{A}^1\times\mathbb{A}^1$?